# Binding a Data Set/Table to a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, data-binding, datagridview

I am currently writing a simple stock control Visual Basic program linked to a database.

[Here's what it looks like so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOx2c.png)

The form displays the data in a DataGrid View and I am trying to refresh my DataGridView automatically when data is changed (using SQL) in the database I am using.

After doing some research I have found that the best way to do this is by binding the data table (using BindingSource) to the DataGridView

However I am struggling to implement this, as every implementation I have tried results in a blank DataGridView and would thoroughly appreciate it if someone could assist me.

Here's the code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Public connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbStock.accdb"
Public conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TblStockControlTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbStockDataSet.tblStockControl)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        ComboBoxQty1.Items.Add(i)
        ComboBoxQty2.Items.Add(i)
    Next

    Dim SqlQuery As String = "Select tblStockControl.[EggType] FROM tblStockControl"
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tblStockControl")
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("tblStockControl")
    'DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        ComboBoxAdd.Items.Add(row.Item(0))
    Next

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        ComboBoxTake.Items.Add(row.Item(0))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddEgg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddEgg.Click

    conn.Open()

    Dim SqlQuery As String = "Select tblStockControl.[Quantity] FROM tblStockControl WHERE EggType = '" & ComboBoxAdd.Text & "'"

    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tblStockControl")
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("tblStockControl")

    Dim qty As Integer = 0

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            qty = row(column)
        Next
    Next

    Dim NewQty As Integer = qty + CInt(ComboBoxQty2.Text)

    UpdateAddQty(NewQty)

    conn.Close()

End Sub

Function UpdateAddQty(ByRef NewQty As Integer) As Integer
    Dim SqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE tblStockControl SET Quantity = '" & NewQty & "' WHERE EggType = '" & ComboBoxAdd.Text & "'"

    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlUpdate
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    Return (Nothing)
End Function

Private Sub btnViewStock_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewStock.Click
    'Add code to open Access file.
End Sub

Private Sub btnTakeEgg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTakeEgg.Click
    conn.Open()

    Dim SqlQuery As String = "Select tblStockControl.[Quantity] FROM tblStockControl WHERE EggType = '" & ComboBoxTake.Text & "'"

    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tblStockControl")
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("tblStockControl")

    Dim qty As Integer = 0

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            qty = row(column)
        Next
    Next

    Dim NewQty As Integer = CInt(ComboBoxQty1.Text) - qty

    UpdateTakeQty(NewQty)

    conn.Close()
End Sub

Function UpdateTakeQty(ByRef NewQty As Integer) As Integer
    Dim SqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE tblStockControl SET Quantity = '" & NewQty & "' WHERE EggType = '" & ComboBoxTake.Text & "'"

    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlUpdate
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    Return (Nothing)
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Which line of code sets the dgv's DataSource?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer The original DataGridView's DataSource was set in the designer (under DataGridView's Tasks) so I don't think that line of code is shown.

Comment: If you're using a typed `DataSet` then use it, otherwise don't use one at all.  Don't mix and match. You obviously do have a typed `DataSet` because you're using a table adapter. In that case, you should ONLY interact with the database via that `DataSet` and/or those table adapters. If you need functionality other than the default then you open the `DataSet` in the designer and make the appropriate modifications. Learn how to work with table adapters [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt3ycf2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: To retrieve data from the database, you call `Fill` on the appropriate table adapter. That's it, that's all. That will populate the appropriate `DataTable` and, if that `DataTable` is already bound to the `DataGridView` as you say then the retrieved data will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `DataTable` , then reset the dataasource of the `DataGridView`.I mean you need to read data from the database again. :

```
'Do this every time you add/Update a data
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn)
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "tblStockControl")
Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("tblStockControl")
```

Or you can just create a row for every data you add to your database :

```
 'Do this every time you add a data
 DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)DataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone()
 row.Cells[0].Value = "Alex"
 row.Cells[1].Value = "Jordan"
 DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: I have tried to add 'DataGridView1.DataSource = dt' after every time I update the data, but for some reason the quantity column remains blank. Any further suggestions?

Comment: or why don't you go with my 2nd option ?

Comment: did it help u ?